# How to fix ‘NSObjectInaccessibleException’ fetch request cannot respond to -entity until used by an NSManagedObjectContext'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

The code works fine in iOS5+:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"FooBar"];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ident"
                                                                                 ascending:NO
                                                                                  selector:@selector(compare:)]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xxx = %@", @"yyy"];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:model.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

But in iOS 4, I got the following error:

```
'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'This fetch request (0x70d4700) 
was created with a string name (FooBar), and cannot respond to -entity 
until used by an NSManagedObjectContext'

2012-11-08 12:12:18.093 hello[1566:11d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'This fetch request 
(0x70d4700) was created with a string name (FooBar), and cannot respond 
to -entity until used by an NSManagedObjectContext'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x012405a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0104a313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x000be68f -[NSFetchRequest entity] + 159
    3   CoreData                            0x0019f7fb -[NSFetchedResultsController initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:] + 763
    ...
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fetchRequestWithEntityName:` is available only in iOS 5 and later.

On iOS 4, you have to create a `NSEntityDescription` first:

```
NSEntityDescription *fooBarEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FooBar" inManagedObjectContext:model.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:fooBarEntity];
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that calling `fetchRequestWithEntityName:` in iOS 4 won't crash the app

Comment: @freestyler: Yes. - I assume that the method is already present in iOS 4, but does not work as in iOS 5. The `NS_AVAILABLE` macro in the header file also claims that it is available in iOS 4, as Dominik noticed in his answer.- But the documentation clearly states that it is available in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the NSFetchRequest has no context to get the object from... you always need a specific context to get an entityDescription from. In ios5 the getting of entityDescription is nicely hidden and delayed till you execute the fetch :)
In for its not

the header is wrong btw. it says its all good for ios4:

```
+ (NSFetchRequest*)fetchRequestWithEntityName:(NSString*)entityName NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
```

Id file a bug. Anyways@Martin R is correct :)